# HttpContext.Current is null after updated to VS 16.5.0 in .net framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

This line of code:

```
 public static object Get(SessionStateKeys key)
        {
            string keyString = Enum.GetName(typeof(SessionStateKeys), key);
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[keyString];
        }
```

it's not working anymore after installation latest verison of VS comunity 16.5.0

HttpContext.Current is null

This happens in several projects using .net framework (not .net core)

is it a bug in vs?

Any help?

Comment: The VS version doesn't affect the *runtime*. There was no change to HttpContext even in the last .NET Framework version, 4.8. Are you running this in a test project perhaps?

Comment: I'm running in debug mode. Yesterday all were fine, today I install vs 16.5.0 and it doesn't works. No change in code was made.

Comment: In release mode works fine!... Why in debug doesn't?

Comment: It is pretty bad to use `HttpContext.Current`. It can be `null` in so many cases, so without seeing your whole project, no one can give you an easy answer.

Comment: Lex Li, before installing VS 16.5.0 no problem in any project, but after instaling VS 16.5.0 all projecta have this problem. It sounds like an issue of this version.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.

In our case, it was an option that started to be selected after the VS 16.5 update.

Go to the Exception Settings screen and uncheck the System.NullReferenceException option.

If compared to previous versions, this option is unchecked by default.

[Exception Settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Bj3.png)